# How can we integrate Salesforce livechat sessions with a hybrid app (similar to an ionic app)?

Tags: ionic-framework, salesforce, livechat, multi-device-hybrid-apps

How can we integrate Salesforce live chat sessions with a hybrid app (similar to an ionic app)